# Problem understanding the Axiom of Foundation

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I am just beginning to learn the ZF axioms of set theory, and I am having trouble understanding the Axiom of Foundation. What exactly does it mean that "every non-empty set $x$ contains a member $y$ such that $x$ and $y$ are disjoint sets." In particular, how can $y$ be an element of a set $x$, and also be disjoint from it (I have seen this be called the epsilon-minimal element). My intuitive understanding of sets (which is obviously wrong) tells me that if $y$ is an element of $x$, then the intersection of $\{y\}$ and $x$ should be $\{y\}$. How can it be $\varnothing$?

Comment: $y\ne\{y\}{}{}$

Answer (score 6):

You need to understand that $y$ and $\{y\}$ are two different things.

Suppose $x = \{ \{ 1,2,3,4\}, \{2,3,4,5\},\{5,6,9,10\}\}.$

Then $x$ has three members.  One of those members is $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  That set has four members.  One of those members is $2$.  That member, $2$, is not a member of $x$.  Similarly each of the other four members of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ fails to be one of the three members of $x$.  So the intersection of $x$ with any of its members is empty.

Now consider the set
$$
x=\Big\{ \quad\varnothing,\quad \big\{\varnothing\big\},\quad \big\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\big\},\quad \big\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\big\}\quad \Big\}.
$$
This set has four members.  One of those members is $\big\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\big\}$.  Another is $\{\varnothing\}$.  Those two sets do have a member in common.  In this case $x$ has only one member that does not intersect $x$.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and example. I get it now!

Comment: If I may ask, which member of $x$ doesn't intersect it? Complete math beginner here (came here after reading something about Haskell; I just want a pointer to which element you mean).

Comment: @Noein : $\varnothing$ is a member of $x$, and $\varnothing$ does not intersect $x$, i.e. there is no member of $x$ that is also a member of $\varnothing$.  That is because $\varnothing$ has no members at all. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It's 3 am over here and this makes sense... scary. I sort of get it now, though. There must be (a) 'most elementary composition part(s)' for a set; something that can't be broken down further into a kind that can belong to the big set, or something like that.

Comment: What about the set $X=\{a,b,c\}$. every member has something in common with the set. i.e. $a\cap X=a$?

Comment: @Averroes2 : No. In some cases it may be true that $a\cap\{a,b,c\} \ne\varnothing,$ but not in most. It is true that $\{a\}\cap\{a,b,c\} = \{a\}.$ But $\{a\}$ and $a$ are two different things. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5):

The axiom isn't saying that $x\cap \{y\}=\emptyset$. It's saying $x\cap y=\emptyset$. Keep in mind that in ZFC everything is a set, including the elements of other sets.