# What's the difference between ${\{a}\}$ and $a$?

Tags: set-theory

${\{a}\}={\{a,{\emptyset}}\}$ ∧ $a={\{a,{\emptyset}}\}$${\implies}{\{a}\}=a$

How is the above wrong?

And if it's actually right, how do we solve the problem with the ZFC axiom of foundation asked [here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780429/problem-understanding-the-axiom-of-foundation)

The answers there seem to solve it by saying that $a≠{\{a}\}$, but by the proof in the beginning of my post $a={\{a}\}$.

Comment: Maybe the point is: anything follows from a false hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

$$\{a\}=\{a,\emptyset\}\land a=\{a,\emptyset\}\implies\{a\}=a$$

This is a true proposition, because $\text{FALSE}\implies\text{FALSE}$.

<s>In particular {a}={a,Ø} is FALSE by the Extensionality</s>, and both $a=\{a,\emptyset\}$ and $\{a\}=a$ are $\text{FALSE}$ by the Foundation.

Comment: @user285146 simply elegant

Comment: The first by itself is not false, since $a=\emptyset $ satisfies it.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf My bad. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

${\{a}\}={\{a,{\emptyset}}\}$ is wrong. Why do you think the equality holds?

Comment: ${\{a}\}={\{a,{\emptyset}}\}$ holds if and only if $a = \emptyset$.  In any case, $a={\{a,{\emptyset}}\}$ is false.

Comment: Isn't there an axiom saying that the empty set is an element of every set?

Comment: @user285146 ...  Certainly not.  The empty set is a subset of every set.  That is quite different.

Comment: @user285146: No, not at all. The empty set is a _subset_ of every set, but being a subset and being an element are _completely different_ properties.

Comment: Let $a,b:a{\neq}b$ be two sets. If they don't share any common elements, we write $a∩b={\emptyset}$. However, the definition of $x∩y$ is a set containing elements belonging to both $x$ and $y$, where $x$ and $y$ are any two sets. So, ${\emptyset}$ seems to belong to both $a$ and $b$. Since for every set $c$ there is always a set $d$ such that $c{\neq}d$, doesn't this mean that empty set is an element of all sets?

Comment: @user285146, no. As you said, if $a$ and $b$ share no common elements, then $a\cap b = \emptyset$, i.e., the set of all common elements of $a$ and $b$ is empty. If $c = a\cap b$, it doesn't mean that $c\in a$ and $c\in b$, it means that $x\in c\implies x\in a\wedge x\in b$. For example $\{0,1\}\cap \{1,2\} = \{1\}$, but $\{1\}$ is not an element of either $\{0,1\}$ or $\{1,2\}$, $1$ is.

Comment: @user285146, you contradict yourself by first saying that $a$ and $b$ share no common elements, but then you say that $\emptyset$ belongs to both. $a$ and $b$ can't simultaneously have no common elements and have a common element.

Answer (score 0):

$\{a\}\neq \{a,\emptyset\}$ because first set has one element and the second has two elements (except in case $a=\emptyset$, as GEdgar points in a comment), so they cannot be equal.

$a\neq \{a,\emptyset\}$ because $a\notin a$.

Comment: By ZFC, every $a$ is a set. What elements does $a=1$ have?

Comment: @user285146, doesn't matter, it certainly does not contain itself by Axiom of foundation. Usually, $1$ is defined as set $\{\emptyset\}$. In that case you have $\{a,\emptyset\} = \{\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\} = 2\neq 1$.